# Add-PnPApp : The request message was already sent. Cannot send the same request message multiple times

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-powershell

I'm new to using Azure DevOps. I continue to receive this error "Add-PnPApp : The request message was already sent. Cannot send the same request message multiple times."

Azure DevOps Release fails because of AddPnP error with "...same request".

Build shows version that changes my version (old) to a new version(gulp's version?).
[Image of build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7yrE.png)

I'm told that it could be the version that starts with zero because SharePoint doesn't like it. I can't seem to change the new version to 1.0.0.1 because it seems like it's being changed in the gulp-file.js. Is there something else that I am missing?

[image of release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tKkN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you need the overwrite parameter in the AddPnP command?  Or is it possible you would need to iterate the version between each release?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpapp?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 0):

In my case the same message

> The request message was already sent. Cannot send the same request message multiple times

was misleading. I tried to update dynamically an `.sppkg` package (which is in fact a ZIP file) during an automated deployment, but the file `_rels/.rels` was getting lost in the process (because of the bug [Unable to compress hidden files with Compress-Archive](https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/66#issuecomment-1149933752)) and the resulting package was corrupted.

Once I fixed the package by making sure the file `_rels/.rels` was kept, the deployment would succeed.